# How to place a button below Imageview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

The layout I used and the result is given. I want the profile Image to overlay the 3+ button. How can I rearrange the layout ?

[image]

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/author_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle">
    </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_more_author"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author_profile_image"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="3+"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just put the "author_profile_image" below of "btn_more_author".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cup_edit_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_round"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_round"
        android:text="3+"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/cup_user_profile"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_userprofile_placeholder" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/author_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle">
    </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_more_author"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/author_profile_image"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="3+"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please try this if you want image in center with button you can use android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" instead of  android:layout_alignParentStart="true".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
CircleImageView profile_image = findViewById(R.id.author_profile_image);
profile_image.bringToFront();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried but no effects :(